# How to add "%" symbol to the value in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

how can I add "%" to the value in the column?

I have Orders like

```
|Orders|
|------|
|  32  |
|------|
|  33  |
```

And I need

```
|Orders|
|------|
| 32%  |
|------|
| 33%  |
|------|
```

Comment: What's the datatype?

Comment: `CONCAT(orders, '%')`

Comment: might want to add an `as orders` or some other identifier so that they can easily reference that via objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting a number as percentage is a display issue, not a data issue. Moreover, it is locale-specific. For instance, in France there needs to be a space between the number and the `'%'` sign, while in Germany and United States there is no space.

Don't add `%` to the value in the database table. Instead, store the number of percents, as an `int`, or a fraction, as a `decimal` with the needed precision.

This way you would retain an ability to manipulate percentages as numbers within the database.